# jQuery: Executing multiple actions on the same event on the same element but at two different points in time

Tags: javascript, jquery

We know that multiple calls to $(document).ready(); in the same page is possible.  I need something similar for click events.

Situation:
Another team implemented this somewhere in an external JS file:

```
$('#element').live('click', function() { /*  Do this */} );
```

It's a live() click listener on #element.  I cannot modify this code or that file, but I need to take an additional action on the same element on the same event.  So, two actions will occur when #element is clicked. In other words, I need this equivalent:

```
$('#element').live('click', function() { /*  Do this */} ); 
/* Some code later... */
$('#element').live('click', function() { /*  Add another action */} );
```

I tried doing the above, but the second call does not fire. It needs to be .live() since #element is being dynamically added.

Is there any way to add more actions to the same event on #element?  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like their event handler is returning false.  Does that stop my call?    $("#element").live('click', function() {p.log_in(); return false; });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are returning false, and that's stopping your event from being fired. See http://api.jquery.com/bind/

> Returning false from a handler is
>   equivalent to calling both
>   .preventDefault() and
>   .stopPropagation() on the event
>   object.

Comment: Nuts...Thanks for the citation in the jQuery doc.  Although I cannot change the other team's code, I just found another way to get around this based on ChessWhiz's answer by looking at the problem differently.  I found that my team controls the HTML on that.  I have added a new class name on #element and targeted that with .live().  That works.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it may be easier to actually unbind the existing live() call and then include it in your own method along with your own code.  That's assuming you're allowed to and it's practical to do so.

Comment: Their call is in a separate library and namespace, so I can't unbind it and add their code into mine.

Answer (score 0):

each time you bind an event handler you install it on a chain of handlers, all of which will get called. So its okay to bind yourself in addition to the code you cant change

Comment: It looks like their event handler is returning false.  Does that stop my addition?    $("#element").live('click', function() {p.log_in(); return false; });